# Dagger 2 dependencies in non-activity classes

Tags: android, dagger-2

So there are many-many tutorials that show how to have a dependency injected into an activity class using Dagger 2. But for some reason dependencies never seem to be inserted into classes that aren't activities/fragments/services. I would like to know how to insert dependencies into a normal class.

Right now, I'm trying to have dagger inject into a field, but the field remains null. I'm assuming the mistake is that I'm not telling dagger to do its injecting. But I'm not sure how to resolve this.

```
@Module
public class TestModule {
    @Provides 
    @Singleton
    String provideTestString() {
        return "test string";
    }
}
```

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { TestModule.class })
public interface TestComponent {
    void inject(TestClass testClass);
    String getTestString();
}
```

```
class TestClass {
    @Inject
    String testString;

    public boolean isTestStringNull() {
        return testString == null;
    }
}
```

```
Log.d("---", "is test string null: " + new TestClass().isTestStringNull());//is true
```

While I may call DaggerTestComponent.create() in a subclass of Application, it won't be available inside random classes that don't know about Application. So what is the correct way to get dagger to initialize my field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class TestClass {
    @Inject
    String testString;

    @Inject
    TestClass() {}
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = { TestModule.class })
public interface TestComponent {
    TestClass testClass();

    String testString();
}

Log.d("---", "is test string null: " + component.testClass().isTestStringNull());//is false
```

Comment: How do you create the component variable? Is that something you need to expose publicly using a singleton?

Comment: `Is that something you need to expose publicly using a singleton?` Generally you create the Singleton version in `Application`, and then use that everywhere else. You create it with `DaggerTestComponent.create()`.

Comment: Hm for some reason I was really uncomfortable about exposing something I created in Application. It felt like bad practice. Though in hindsight I don't know why I thought that. Seems silly now. Oh well, thank you!

Comment: If you check https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/that-missing-guide-how-to-use-dagger2-ef116fbea97 , I create it in Application, and make the getter globally accessible as a `static`

Answer (score 1):

Every application has an entrance. So instead of Application, you can use some top-level class. The approach is similar to one with Activity or even easier because you can pass required classes into a constructor.

Comment: Are you suggesting doing DaggerTestComponent.create() somewhere, saving the returned variable and exposing it through a static method?

Comment: Depending on a life cycle of the variables. If an instance should have only one-per-app - use @Singleton. Otherwise - you can generate instances right before you need it.